# SVG fill of type linearGradient is not displayed

Tags: jquery, css, svg, datatables

I hope somebody out there might experienced this strange behaviour of a svg linear gradient fill, which is not displayed resp. applied at all in standard browsers. Other properties as the stroke work as expected, but not the fill! The element seems to be transparent.

I actually figured out that there might be side effects with a jquery Data Table which is placed on the same page as the SVG element.

```
<svg viewBox="0 12.705 512 486.59" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" style="margin-right: 0px;">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="jRate_grad1">        
            <stop stop-color="white" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <polygon points="256.814,12.705 317.205,198.566 512.631,198.566 354.529,313.435 414.918,499.295 256.814,384.427 98.713,499.295 159.102,313.435 1,198.566 196.426,198.566 " style="fill: url(#jRate_grad1);stroke:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:2px;"/>
</svg>
```

The svg code is generated by the jquery rating plugin [jRate](https://github.com/senthilporunan/jRate).

A test site setup which reproduces the "error" can be found [here](http://kisters-dev.crealistiques.de/datatable/). The SVG elements are those little cross symbols in the table column "Bewertung".

Comment: swap the two stop elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#StopElementOffsetAttribute)

> Each gradient offset value is required to be equal to or greater than the previous gradient stop's offset value. If a given gradient stop's offset value is not equal to or greater than all previous offset values, then the offset value is adjusted to be equal to the largest of all previous offset values.

Your offset values decrease rather than increase so you won't see a gradient.

The other problem in your site (but not in your question) is that you're using a base tag.

```
<base href="http://kisters-dev.crealistiques.de/">
```

This means that

```
fill: url(#rating_40_grad2)
```

becomes

```
fill: url(http://kisters-dev.crealistiques.de/#rating_40_grad2)
```

because [that's what base tags do](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html). But the linearGradient is in the page itself which is located at `http://kisters-dev.crealistiques.de/datatable/`

No match means no gradient.

Comment: It turns out that the order of the stop color definition makes no difference and the fill is still not displayed!

As mentioned in my original question there must be some side effects because the same code works in another environment/on another page.

Comment: cars10 answer above sure works for me on my browser. If there's something else going on that's not in the question it's rather hard to help you.

Comment: Thank you Robert, your're right! I now included a link to a test site above.

Comment: A test site showing the SVG elements not working can be found [here](http://kisters-dev.crealistiques.de/datatable/).

Comment: @Steven the other problem is the base tag you're using, as I've now explained above.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert, your answer solved this issue for me. I was not aware of the fact that the base tag has any effect on the fill url which is rather quite obvious now to me. Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Like Robert said:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 12.705 512 486.59" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200" style="margin-right: 0px;">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1">        
            <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <polygon points="256.814,12.705 317.205,198.566 512.631,198.566 354.529,313.435 414.918,499.295 256.814,384.427 98.713,499.295 159.102,313.435 1,198.566 196.426,198.566" style="fill: url(#grad1);stroke:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:9px;"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly there are multiple gradients with the same id on your page. Make it unique and it will work.